# Free Linux Cluster Build for Small Scale Reseach

Tags: linux, ubuntu, parallel-processing, mpi, cluster-computing

I need to build a small cluster for my research. It's pretty humble and I'd like to build a cluster just with my other 3 laptops at home.

I'm writing in C++. My codes in MPI framework are ready. I can simulate them using visual studio 2010 and they're fine. Now I want to see the real thing.

I want to do it free (I'm a student). I have ubuntu installed and I wonder:

1. if I could build a cluster using ubuntu. I couldn't find a clear answer to that on the net.
2. if not, is there a free linux distro that I can use at building cluster?
3. I also wonder if I have to install ubuntu, or the linux distro on the host machine to all other laptops. Will any other linux distribution (like openSUSE) work with the one at the host machine? Or do all of them have to be same linux distro?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In principle, any linux distro will work with the cluster, and also in principle, they can all be different distros.  In practice, it'll be a enormously easier with everything the same, and if you get a distribution which already has a lot of your tools set up for you, it'll go much more quickly.

To get started, something like the [Bootable Cluster CD](http://bccd.net/) should be fairly easy -- I've not used it myself yet, but know some who have.   It'll let you boot up a small cluster without overwriting anything on the host computer, which lets you get started very easily.   Other distributions of software for clusters include [Rocks](http://www.rocksclusters.org/wordpress/) and [Oscar](http://svn.oscar.openclustergroup.org/trac/oscar/wiki).  A technical discussion on building a cluster can be found [here](http://www.beowulf.org/overview/howto.html).

Answer (score 0):

I also liked PelicanHPC when I used it a few years back. I was more successful getting it to work that with Rocks, but it is much less popular.

http://pareto.uab.es/mcreel/PelicanHPC/

Just to get a cluster up and running is actually not very difficult for the situation you're describing. Getting everything installed and configured just how you want it though can be quite challenging. Good luck!